# how to upload images using web api 2 REST API

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I am new to web api 2. I tried a lot but did not find proper working code for uploading images in web api 2.

I have a working code that is working in web api (old), but in web api 2, this particular value is null. **HttpContext.Current**

Can someone provide me working code?

Comment: Please read https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2

Comment: But I am using web api2 project and instead of ApiController, it has Controller class. And also getting null for HttpContext.Current

Comment: My project is Web API2 too, and I am using the code from that link. It's working

Answer (score 0):

Here is the controller in one of my Web API 2 projects:

```
namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    public class FilesController : ApiController
    {        
        // POST api/<controller>        
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
        {
            // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }

            string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
            var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

            try
            {
                // Read the form data.
                await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

                // This illustrates how to get the file names.
                foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
                {
                    Debug.Listeners[0].WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
                    Debug.Listeners[0].WriteLine("Server file path: " + file.LocalFileName);
                }
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
            }
        }       
        ...
    }
}
```

You can try by adding a `Web API Controller class (v2.1)`.